# Is there any way to increase the amount of exception description text that Google Analytics gives me for my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, flurry

It seems like Google Analytics is limiting the text of the errors coming from my iPhone app that I get whenever I check out the details...

Is there any way for it to report longer errors?

Is Flurry any better at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry will soon be providing Full Stack Trace crash reports for iOS apps. Currently, this feature is available for Android apps using the new Flurry SDK v3.x.
(Full Disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)